# Array[Nothing with java.lang.Object] required in Scala 2.9.1

Tags: arrays, swing, scala, intellij-idea, scala-2.9

I have a weird compilation error. The offending lines are:

```
val comboBoxLanguage = new javax.swing.JComboBox
//...
comboBoxLanguage.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel( 
    Array[Object]("Scala", "Java")))
```

and the error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Array[java.lang.Object]
required: Array[Nothing with java.lang.Object]
Note: java.lang.Object >: Nothing with java.lang.Object, but class Array is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ >: Nothing with java.lang.Object`. (SLS 3.2.10)
comboBoxLanguage.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel( Array[Object]("Scala", "Java")))
```

According to JavaDoc the constructor of `DefaultComboBoxModel` expects an `Object[]`, which can be a `String[]` or whatever array type in Java, since arrays are covariant, but in Scala they are not, so we have to use `Array[Object]`, which shouldn't be a problem.

Why is the compiler expecting `Array[Nothing with java.lang.Object]`? How can I fix it?

This seems to be new with version 2.9.1 of Scala. My application used to compile until I installed 2.9.1 a couple of days ago. A confusing / worrying thing is that I haven't changed the project compiler library version in IntelliJ, but somehow it seems to be using it, perhaps grabbing it from my SCALA_HOME environment variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is not an issue of scala 2.9.1 but new JDK. In JDK7 `JComboBox` is generic and in your code it is `JComboBox[Nothing]`. You should explicitly declare `comboBoxLanguage` variable as

```
val comboBoxLanguage = new javax.swing.JComboBox[Object]
```

Comment: Excellent, that solves it, thanks. I don't know why IntelliJ was trying to use Java 7 to compile it, as it's set to "1.6" in the Project SDK field. So I've de-selected "make" in the run configuration, and leave sbt to do the compilation using the correct Java version (6).

Comment: @LuigiPlinge (compiling with java 7), this seems like it's a classic problem, when compiling with java 7, you're using the java 7 libraries, even if you're in compatbility mode. If you're using maven, you can look at http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer/